# Recognize parameter from URL correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get values from the URL in the browser.

Here is the URL:

`http://localhost/order=1&data=2&redirectURL=http://localhost:8081?param=abc&checkoutURL=htto://localhost:8082?test=abc`

I want to extract the value of redirectURL and checkoutURL, but here is the result I get

```
order = 1
data=2
redirectURL=http://localhost:8081
```

I can't get the full value of redirectURL and can't get the value after it ( value of checkoutURL param)

here is my code:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
let redirectUrl = urlParams.get('redirectURL');
let checkoutUrl = urlParams.get('checkoutURL');
console.log(redirectUrl); // http://localhost:8081 , expected: http://localhost:8081?param=abc
console.log(checkoutUrl); // null , expected:
```

Is there anyway to achieve it or I did something wrong. Please help me

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your first param `redirectURL` has an URL in the value which is supposed to be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`
Make sure, when you append URL in the parameter on your website url its encoded.

After the first `?` operator on your website URL parameters are appended.
your first param `redirectURL` also has `?` present in it, Javascript reads this as an entire URL param value. which escapes your second param.